# LINQ: Problem using DB with relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know how can I return posts to my view where their tags are equal to those who are passed to controller action.
I think there is some clever and easy way of doing this but I am very new to LINQ and SQL.
[image: DB]

**Code**

```
// id = tag name, not it's id
public ActionResult Tag(string id)
{
    // I get all the PostTags where PostTags.Tag.Name = id
    var postTags = _db.PostTags.Where(x => x.Tag.Name == id);

    // And what I do now?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using joins in relational data is easier to grasp as a novice using query syntax instead of extension methods. The following is possible with extension methods (like .Join(...), etc), but this is closer to the SQL you might already be used to.

```
var postTags = from t in _db.Tags
               join pt in _db.PostTags on t.ID equals pt.TagID
               join p in _db.Posts on pt.PostID equals p.ID
               where t.Name == id
               select p;
```

Comment: i think join is redundant if the relationship is already mapped in the LINQ class.

Comment: @J.W. I agree, Quintin's advanced answer demonstrates the relationships. However, if you're struggling with lambdas and expression trees, extension syntax can be a bit daunting. Query syntax is closer to what the developer has already seen

Answer (score 0):

Well to select them you could do something similar to..

```
var posts = _db.Posts.Where(post => post.PostTags.Any(postTag => postTag.Tag.Name == id));
```

This will just select all `Post`s where any of the related `PostTag`s has a `Tag` with the name passed.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I will analyze it a bit more so that I understand what is happening there.